# Error while uploading/passing the pdf from Java to marklogic rest api

Tags: java, marklogic

I have a rest api written in xquery where i need 2 variables one as xml node and the other as pdf but that pdf will be passed from JAVA and while sending it from JAVA to Marklogic it is not able to fetch the pdf but the same i am able to fetch using postman .I have also verified the content type as multipart/form-data...but still not working..
Any help/suggestions.?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what the problem may be without more details. What do you mean by “unable to fetch the PDF”? Show some code. Also, are you getting any errors? If so, post the error from MarkLogic reply or the Java stack trace.

Comment: @MadsHansen I am using the below code in rewriter.xqy to fetch 2 parameters in my rest API.
Param1 node=<Metadata>
   <FileName>Test.xml</FileName>
   </Metadata>
Param2 file=sample.pdf
let $paramNames:= xdmp:get-request-field-names()
                            for $eachParam in $paramNames
                             let $paramValue := xdmp:get-request-field($eachParam)
   return concat($eachParam,'=',$paramValue)         On calling rewriter.xqy from JAVA above code "xdmp:get-request-field-names()" does not renders either node or pdf.Request is POST method and is multipart/form-data

Comment: @MadsHansen   Is there some different way to post PDF/binary from JAVA to ML .?I want to pas pdf alongwith xmlnode from JAVA to ingest in Marklogic with rest api but it is unable to fetch multipart/form data i believe..

Comment: There's an example for multipart/form-data at https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/xdmp:get-request-field . I'd try it outside Java, maybe curl, and then try to get Java to do what works.